# Using a if or CASE WHEN with AND statements in a Where Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to modify my Stored Producer to become one Big statement instead of using 3 different updates. The issue I am facing is in the where condition. The SP allows you to pass in NULL for any of the three parameters RA/RS/IC. So If they are NULL I don't want to do RA = @OldRA in the where condition. This works in the Single updates because nothing would match.

I have tried using IF / CASE WHEN in my where but I'm having trouble figure out how to work with the NULL values on these. IF it's NULL I don't want it to be in the AND right? SO say I pass in a RA and an RS I need RA = OLDRA and RS = OLDRS but not IC = OLDIC because we don't want to match on these. Is there a possilbe solution to this case?

```
/*3 Updates */
UPDATE xxx fai
SET fai.RS = @RS
WHERE fai.RS = @OldRS

UPDATE xxx fai
SET fai.RA = @RA
WHERE fai.RA = @OldRA

UPDATE xxx fai
SET fai.IC = @IC
WHERE fai.IC = @OldIC

/*New BIG STATEMENT */


UPDATE 
 xxx fai 
SET 
  fai.RS = CASE WHEN `fai.RS` = '' 
  or `fai.RS` IS NULL THEN `xxx` ELSE @RS END, 
  fai.RA = CASE WHEN `fai.RA` = '' 
  or `fai.RA` IS NULL THEN `xxx` ELSE @RA END, 
  fai.IC = CASE WHEN `fai.IC` = '' 
  or `fai.IC` IS NULL THEN @IC ELSE `xx` END 
WHERE 
  fai.RS = @OldRS AND fai.RA = @OldRA AND fai.IC = @OldIC
```

Comment: show a table of results and its scenario cheers

Comment: Don't put backticks around `fai.RS`. That's preventing the `.` from being treated as a separator between the table and column names.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement should work:

```
UPDATE 
 xxx fai 
SET 
  fai.RS = CASE WHEN fai.RS = '' 
  or fai.RS IS NULL THEN fai.RS ELSE @RS END, 
  fai.RA = CASE WHEN fai.RA = '' 
  or fai.RA IS NULL THEN fai.RA ELSE @RA END, 
  fai.IC = CASE WHEN fai.IC = '' 
  or fai.IC IS NULL THEN fai.IC ELSE @IC END 
WHERE 
  fai.RS = @OldRS OR fai.RA = @OldRA OR fai.IC = @OldIC
```

That being said using 3 separate statements would give a better performance.

Comment: Agree with Melvin.  Just because you can combine a set of operations into one statement doesn't mean you should.  You will want to evaluate whether the single statement provides sufficient performance vs. the individual 3 statements.